# if and else in Python,if age is true grade is false,this program print is wrong

Tags: python

```
age = float(raw_input("Enter your age: "))
grade = int(raw_input("Enter your grade: "))
if age >= 8:
    if grade >= 3:
        print "You can play this game."
else:
    print "Sorry, you can't play the game."
```

if age is true and grade is false,this program prints wrong output.but if age is false, it prints correct output.

Why is it happening?

Comment: *if age is true grade is false* - you have nothing to handle this condition. It won't print anything unless you do an `else` in the nested `if` as well

Comment: "prints wrong output"...You haven't said what is correct and incorrect output.

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan thank，i finally got it

Comment: @MarkTolonen  yes, it's missing an else so it won't print anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are leaving open the possibility that `age >= 8` but `grade < 3` in which you have no control flow to handle.  You can correct this succinctly with an `and` statement

```
age = float(raw_input("Enter your age: "))
grade = int(raw_input("Enter your grade: "))
if age >= 8 and grade >= 3:
    print "You can play this game."
else:
    print "Sorry, you can't play the game."
```

Answer (score 0):

```
age = float(raw_input("Enter your age: "))
grade = int(raw_input("Enter your grade: "))
if age >= 8:
    if grade >= 3:
        print"You can play this game."
    else:
        print"Sorry , you can't play the game."
else:
    print "Sorry , you can't play the game."
```

Comment: While this code snippet might answer the question, it's always better to add some explanation that could be helpful for other readers too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include an 'else' condition in your nested if/else statement:

```
age = float(raw_input("Enter your age: "))
grade = int(raw_input("Enter your grade: "))
if age >= 8:
    if grade >= 3:
        print "You can play this game."
    else:
        print"Sorry, you can't play this game."
else:
    print "Sorry, you can't play this game."
```

Comment: Excuse me，do if and else have to be used together ？